# Prestashop: Undefined Smarty variables in order-detail.tpl

Tags: smarty, prestashop

In order-detail.tpl, there are variables such as {$is_guest} and {$return_allowed}. A little debugging (using Javascript alert) shows that {$is_guest} is undefined for some reason and {$return_allowed} returns 0 even though I allowed returns. This is leading to the order-detail page hiding merchandise return section.

All these Smarty variables are defined in root/controllers/OrderDetailController.php, so I don't know what's causing the errors.

I'm using Prestashop 1.4.9. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own question. Go to root/controllers/OrderDetailController.php. Around line 144, change

```
'is_guest' => false,
```

to

```
'is_guest' => "false",
```

And also, change

```
{if !$is_guest}
```

to

```
{if $is_guest == "false"}
```

As for $return_allowed, it turns out that the items must be marked as delivered first in the BO. It is defined such that it is false unless paid for + delivered + before return deadline.